# I can't find this error when I make API 31, there are these 3 errors in each of my projects

Tags: android, firebase, performance, android-studio, android-layout

Merging Errors:
Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. app main manifest (this file), line 57

Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. .app main manifest (this file), line 93
Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
.app main manifest (this file), line 100

Answer (score 0):

It explains itself s you need to add  `android:exported="true or false"` for your Receiver GcmBroadcastReceiver

If u don't intend to upload your app to play Store you can downgrade your API to 30 and it will work without you adding android:exported for every activity.

Comment: all ready add but 3 error will be come

Comment: In that case Some of the dependencies you have might not have android:exported.  You can add that manually in your Manifest

Comment: `<receiver android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false" />`

Comment: THAT IS SOULTION  ADD IN MENIFEST FILE IN ANDROID APP<receiver android:name="com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver"
            android:exported="false"></receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver"
            android:exported="false"></receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver"
            android:exported="false"></receiver>

Comment: thanks bro Seife

Comment: If u found the answer correct please mark it as accepted.